# Ruby on Rails: Many to Many error when trying to add to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have 2 models (`model1` and `model2`) that have a many to many relationship.  A table already exists which only contains the primary key from each model.  The `has_many through` relationships are set up in their respective models.  However, when I try the following in a POST, I get the classic

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!    
You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while 
evaluating nil.[]":
```

```
model1 = Model1.find(params[:id])
model2 = Model2.find(params[:model2_id])
model1.model2s << model2
```

`model1` is not nil.  `model1.model2s` is not nil.  `model2` is not nil.  Where is this error coming from?

Comment: It's saying `nil.[]`. The brackets refer to an indexing operation, like `params[:id]`. Is `params` nil for some reason? Did you read your error message properly..does it not say what line the error is on?

Comment: `params` is not nil.  The error is occurring at `model.model2s << model2` according to the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a join table that **only** has the primary keys from each of your models then you want `has_and_belongs_to_many` not `has_many :through`

Comment: Thanks, @smathy, this did the trick!  For those that come later, in this situation, the relationship table was set to something other than model1_model2.  This can be set with the `:join_table =>` option.